# r: Summarizing Data Frame Using Group By

Tags: r, dplyr

I have daily data (`df$date` is the daily field):

[image]

Which I want to group by week (`df$wbm` = "week beginning monday") in a new data frame (`df2`). When I run the below statement, the data frame that is returned is the same as the original:

```
df2<- df%>%
  group_by(wbm)
```

The function runs without throwing an error, but it just produces the same data frame. 
[image]

How can I drop `date` and ensure that my variables are grouped by `wbm`?

Comment: You only added the group by attribute.  If you need to summarise, use `summarise`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `group_by` steps adds a grouping attribute, but we didn't give any command as to how to summarise it.  If we need to get the `sum` of the columns that have column names as 'var' grouped by 'wbm', then use `summarise_at`

```
library(dplyr)
df%>%
   group_by(wbm) %>%
   summarise_at(vars(matches('^var\\d+$')), sum)
```

If it is only a single column to be summarised, it can be `summarise`

```
df %>%
   group_by(wbm) %>%
   summarise(var1 = sum(var1))
```

Comment: "If we need" , "If it is". If the question is unclear, please ask OP for clarification instead of guessing. Cheers.